# EAGLE - put "symbol" and corresponding "packages" in the "schematics view"

Tags: eaglecad, cad

So in EAGLE every library has "**devices**" which usualy have one "**symbol**" and more corresponding "**packages**" available for that "**symbol**". So EAGLE only shows a symbol part in the "**schematics view**" and only package part in the "**board view**".

But how can instruct EAGLE to draw a package part in "**scheatics view**"? I would like to put it right next to the "**symbol**".

Answer (score 2):

You can import a *bitmap image* into a schematic using import-bmp.ulp.  You would need to somehow save the schematic as a bitmap, maybe using a snip tool.  You can even make the bitmap part of the symbol in the library.

Comment: Yea but this is ton of work right... There must be some other way. And I would have to save package as the bitmap and import iit afterwards. I don't like importing bitmaps, because they are imported as bunch of planes...

Comment: I don't believe there is another way @71GA.  Packages have zero meaning in the schematic, so the schematic editor is just not made to deal with them.

Comment: Well it should in order for EAGLE to be able to provide even better technical documantation. :)

Comment: @71GA All that you need to know about what package the part is can be found in the attributes. It should be possible to make the attributes visible on the seer so you can see the name of the package. An picture of the package is pretty much meaningless without any sense of scale.